# How to set character whitelist in Firebase Vision Text Recognizer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I'm using Firebase Vision Text Recognizer (On Device Text Recognizer) and I want to limit characters to numbers only. I can do this in tesseract like this:
`tesseract.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "0123456789");`

I know that I can filter the output but in my case, it doesn't help. I want to know is there any way to do the same thing in FirebaseVision?

Thanks.